# Overlapping absolute layers: Click on the back one

Tags: css, position, layer, absolute

This is the idea, the red square behind the black layer should be clickeable:

[image]

If I apply z-index, it doesn't work because the red layer is behind the black layer:

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: I think they want to have the red area behind the overlaying div, but still making it clickable.

Comment: Is the clickable part a rectangle always? If so, you could try to create a dummy div matching to the dimensions and locations, set z-index for that properly and catch the click there.